# change images with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, class

I need help with jquery code.

On my website I have a header. When I move to down website this header is "sticky". Like here: http://markgoodyear.com/labs/headhesive/

```
var options = { 
    offset: '#showHere', 
    classes: { 
        clone: 'banner--clone', 
        stick: 'banner--stick', 
        unstick: 'banner--unstick' 
    } 
}; 
var banner = new Headhesive('.banner', options);
```

Please look on my code:

```
<header id="intro-header" class="banner banner--clone">
  <div id="container">
  <div id="content">
  <div class="logo">
<img class="main-logo" alt="" src="images/logo.png">
```

Now my header is on top.

When I move to down my website I get new class:

```
<header id="intro-header" class="banner banner--clone banner--stick">
  <div id="container">
  <div id="content">
  <div class="logo">
<img class="main-logo" alt="" src="images/logo.png">
```

My question is: How I can change image "LOGO.PNG" to "LOGO-CLONE.PNG" when I move my website to down after added new class?

Please write for me short code :)
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code too please. You need to update the `src` of that element when the code runs to change the header size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way using jquery

```
$(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
       //Check for class 
       if( $("#intro-header").hasClass( "banner--stick") ) {
           $("#intro-header.banner.banner--stick")
             .find('img.main-logo')
             .attr('src', 'images/LOGO-CLONE.PNG'); 
         } else {
          //Show old logo
           $("#intro-header.banner")
             .find('img.main-logo')
             .attr('src', 'images/LOGO.PNG');
       }
   })
});
```

**Edit**

Now since you have added the js code, you can use this method

```
var options = { 
  offset: '#showHere', 
  classes: { 
    clone: 'banner--clone', 
    stick: 'banner--stick', 
    unstick: 'banner--unstick' 
  }, 
  onStick: function() {
    //Check for class 
     $("#intro-header.banner.banner--stick")
            .find('img.main-logo')
            .attr('src', 'images/LOGO-CLONE.PNG'); 

  },
  onUnstick: function() {
     //Show old logo
     $("#intro-header.banner")
           .find('img.main-logo')
           .attr('src', 'images/LOGO.PNG');

   }
};
```